# Changing the subnet address for network of routers

Tags: python, ip-address, packet, subnet, mininet

I'm using Mininet's API with python, right now all these addresses are on the same subnet for the network that connects the 3 routers (192.168.1.0/24) how do I make these unique? Do I change the netmasks?

```
    r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth0 inet 10.1.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0')

    #connect routers

    r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth1 inet 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth2 inet 192.168.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth0 inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth1 inet 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth2 inet 10.1.2.6 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r3.cmd('ifconfig r3-eth0 inet 192.168.1.4 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r3.cmd('ifconfig r3-eth1 inet 192.168.1.6 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r3.cmd('ifconfig r3-eth2 inet 10.1.3.27 netmask 255.255.255.0')


    # Add static routes
    info( '*** Adding static routes\n')

    r1.cmd('ip route add 10.1.9.1/24 via 192.168.1.2 dev r1-eth1')
    r2.cmd('ip route add 10.1.9.2/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev r2-eth0')

    r1.cmd('ip route add 10.1.7.1/24 via 192.168.1.4 dev r1-eth2')
    r3.cmd('ip route add 10.1.7.2/24 via 192.168.1.3 dev r3-eth0')

    r2.cmd('ip route add 10.1.8.2/24 via 192.168.1.6 dev r2-eth1')
    r3.cmd('ip route add 10.1.8.1/24 via 192.168.1.5 dev r3-eth1')
```

Comment: How do you make what "unique"? The IP address? The subnet?

Comment: @RossJacobs the ip's are already unique aren't they? I think I need different subnets otherwise the router won't know where to send the packets for a particular subnet right?

Comment: `r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth1 inet 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0')` will create an interface with IP 192.168.1.1 int he 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. `r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth1 inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0')` would put this in a separate 192.168.2.0/24 subnet. Generally speaking, you should put different interfaces on a router in different subnets.

Comment: @RossJacobs I see, so I could use 192.168.1.0/24 for one router, and then 192.168.2.0/24 for another, etc.?

Comment: You could. I would read the answer to this question, as it's better to understand how traffic is sent across subnets first: https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work